# C, C++: Duplicate Header File Inclusions Across Multiple Files - Preprocessor/ Compiler Behavior & Best Practices

Tags: c, include, header-files, include-guards

The following question, despite being slightly compound, all relate to the single overarching concept of compiler behavior with regards to a same header file inclusion within multiple source files.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361239/c-language-proper-usage-of-include-guards) seems to suggest that include guards for standard include files are already implemented internally. The question therefore concerns non-standard include files.

Consider the following situation:

> A C program has files `module1.c`, `module2.c`, `module1.h`, `module2.h`, `apputils.c` and `apputils.h`.

> Both `module1.c` and `module2.c` make use of functions defined/ implemented within `apputils.c` and `apputils.h`.

> Aside from required headers, **each `.c` file includes their respective `.h` file only**.

- In terms of double inclusion conflict, if code sections presented below are added to specified files (*`apputils.c` inclusive*), which cases:

  1. Are valid?
  2. Cause issue?
  3. Treated the same by the compiler?

     - Case 1 (within ALL):

       ```
       #ifndef APPUTIL_H
       #define APPUTIL_H

       #include "apputils.h"

       #endif
       ```
     - Case 2 (within `module1.c` and `module2.c`):

       ```
       #include "apputils.h"
       ```
     - Case 3 (within `module1.h` and `module2.h`):

       ```
       #include "apputils.h"
       ```
- Does it matter if the inclusions are `<...>` or `"..."`?
- Finally, for reference, please specify the recommended approach for the matter.

Comment: If you don't know about the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) this seems like a good time to learn about it.

Comment: Dual-tagging a question with both C and C++ tags is problematic and more likely to attract downvotes and opprobrium than upvotes and kudos.  Choose one language or the other unless your question is about the interworking between the languages or differences between the languages (and be cautious even then).

Comment: Look at [Self-sufficient header files in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1892043/15168) and [Should I use `#include` in headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1804486/15168)  The discuss many of the nuances.  Header guards belong in the header file unconditionally.  It generally isn't worth repeating the header guards in files that use the header.  All else apart, it means that if the header guards in a header change for any reason, you have to edit the code that uses that header.  Therefore, Case 1 is not a good idea.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_  Case 2 is correct if the modules use the facilities exposed by `apputils.h` but do not expose them in their interface to the outside world.  It is often the right choice.  OTOH, Case 3 is correct if `apputils.h` defines a type which is used in the interface to one of the externally exposed functions declared by `apputils.h`.  It is plausible for one of the module headers to include `apputils.h` and the other not to do so.  It all depends on what it takes to make the headers self-contained and minimal.  (Properly used, header guards ensure the headers are idempotent.)

Comment: TLDR:  ***1.***  **ALWAYS** put header guards in all header file, therefore ***2.*** You can stop worrying about it.

Comment: thank you for all this information. this is the answer i'm looking for so please feel free to paste the posts as answer and i'll accept it.
i apologize in advance because this isn't a comment discussion, so please feel free to ignore the following questions:

Comment: regarding what you say about case 2, does it mean that if i have say a typedef in apputils.h, and i use it in module1.c but dont 'expose' it - as in perhaps with a function that returns the struct, then i should be fine? case 2 specifically has no include guard, so would it not cause exception during chained compilation (or even during modular compilation creating the final output by linking all separately .o files)?

Comment: where can i get more information on this matter? because the phrasing is so complicated and the issue is so concentrated, any search leads me to _solutions_ instead of the _why_ of the problem.

Comment: we can _avoid_ these issues by designing our source files in some way. but then we're not addressing the fundamental problem head on. i still believe this question should not be closed as this attempts to ask about the cause of a problem that has many answers on SO on how to solve it _only_.

Comment: The `#ifndef APPUTIL_H` stuff should be in the `.h` files, around the entire contents, not the `.c` files. This ensures that each header file is only processed once, no matter how many times it's included.

Comment: Header files accessed with `<...>` are the implementation-provided headers. They are guaranteed to do this so you don't have to write your own protection.

Comment: thanks for your comment. i can explain my issue more clearly now - what if ```#include "apputils.h"``` appears within the guards of BOTH module1.h and module2.h those guards are different so would'nt this cause a conflict then? leaving aside best practice of course, like this ```#ifndef MOD1_H\#define MOD1_H\#include "apputils.h"\...\#endif``` and the same in module2.h but with the guard label changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at these two Stack Overflow questions:

1. [Self-sufficient header files in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1892043/15168)
2. [Should I use #include in headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1804486/15168)

They discuss many of the nuances.  They also discuss the concepts that header files should be self-contained, idempotent, and minimal.  (Header guards ensure idempotency.)

- **Header guards belong in the header file unconditionally.**

That is, each header file should have the form:

```
/* Optional comments */
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED

…main content of the header…

#endif /* HEADER_H_INCLUDED */
```

The name of the guard macro should be unique across all headers that will ever be included in the same translation unit (TU).  It is usually derived from the header file name (which should also be unique to avoid confusion).

It generally isn't worth repeating the header guards in files that use the header. All else apart, it means that if the header guards in a header change for any reason, you have to edit the code that uses that header<sup>(1)</sup>.  Therefore, Case 1 is not a good idea.

Additionally, with Case 1, the headers should be responsible for defining the header guard macros (the `#define` should not be in the source code including the header).  If the source code testing the header guards sets the header guard correctly, that will prevent the contents of the file from being included.

Case 2 is correct if the modules use the facilities exposed by `apputils.h` but do not expose them in their interface to the outside world. It is often the right choice.

OTOH, Case 3 is correct if `apputils.h` defines a type which is used in the interface to one of the externally exposed functions declared by either `module1.h` or `module2.h`. It is plausible for one of the module headers to include `apputils.h` and the other not to do so. It all depends on what it takes to make the headers self-contained and minimal. (Properly used, header guards ensure the headers are idempotent.)

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77701939/c-c-duplicate-header-file-inclusions-across-multiple-files-preprocessor-c#comment136991577_77701939), [mindoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15394019/mindoverflow) asked:

> I can explain my issue more clearly now - what if `#include "apputils.h"` appears within the guards of BOTH `module1.h` and `module2.h`.  Those guards are different, so wouldn't this cause a conflict then? Leaving aside best practice of course, like this:
>
> ```
> #ifndef MODULE1_H
> #define MODULE1_H
>
> #include "apputils.h"
>
> ...
>
> #endif /* MODULE1_H */
> ```
>
> and the same in `module2.h` but with the guard label changed?

There's no problem as long as the contents of `apputils.h` has header guards around it:

```
#ifndef APPUTILS_H
#define APPUTILS_H

...

#endif /* APPUTILS_H */
```

Suppose `module1.h` is included before `module2.h`.

- The `module1.h` header defines `MODULE1_H`
- It includes `apputils.h`
- The `apputils.h` header defines `APPUTILS_H`
- It also defines the other material it needs to
- The `module1.h` header defines the other material it needs to
- The `module2.h` is included
- The `module2.h` defines `MODULE2_H`
- It includes `apputils.h`
- Since `APPUTILS_H` is already defined, the contents of `apputils.h` is ignored on this second use
- The `module2.h` header defines the other material it needs to

So, the net result is that the material from each of `apputils.h`, `module1.h` and `module2.h` is defined once, just as you wanted.  If `module2.h` was included before `module1.h`, the effect would be similar — the operational content of each header would appear once in the translation unit, albeit with the content of `module2.h` appearing before the content of `module1.h`.

This is precisely why it is crucial that the headers are self-protecting (contain the header guards), and also why it is important (if you go against advice and still decide to test for header guards before including the file) that you do not write:

```
#ifndef MODULE1_H
#define MODULE1_H
#include "module1.h"
#endif /* MODULE1_H */
```

But instead use:

```
#ifndef MODULE1_H
#include "module1.h"
#endif /* MODULE1_H */
```

If you use the first notation, you prevent the content from `module1.h` from being included because the header guard is already defined when the file is read.  That's not what you intended and is pointless.  But it depends on the header guards being in the header file.  Not putting the header guards in the header file is very bad practice.

Think how horrible it would be if you had to write:

```
#ifndef STDC_STDIO_H
#include <stdio.h>
#define STDC_STDIO_H
#endif /* STDC_STDIO_H */
```

instead of just:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Not nice — and not necessary.

---

In a another [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77701939/c-c-duplicate-header-file-inclusions-across-multiple-files-preprocessor-c/77705375?noredirect=1#comment136992459_77705375), [mindoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15394019/mindoverflow) asks:

> […] It is exactly because the header guard would prevent a double inclusion that I ask this. If I had included other headers [that] I needed for each module within the guard such that the contents within the guard are different in each module, that would definitely cause issues, right?

I'm not completely sure what you're asking, but …

If you mean that the headers `module1.h` and `module2.h` had each included other headers, but the sets of headers were different, there would be no problem as long as each of the headers was idempotent (contained its own header guards).

Note that the C standard requires analogous behaviour with C11 [§7.1.2 Standard header files ¶4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.2p4):

> Standard headers may be included in any order; each may be included more than once in a given scope, with no effect different from being included only once, except that the effect of including `<assert.h>` depends on the definition of `NDEBUG` (see 7.2). If used, a header shall be included outside of any external declaration or definition, and it shall first be included before the first reference to any of the functions or objects it declares, or to any of the types or macros it defines. However, if an identifier is declared or defined in more than one header, the second and subsequent associated headers may be included after the initial reference to the identifier.

The last quoted sentence applies to the type `size_t`, for example, which is defined by `<stddef.h>`, but also by `<stdio.h>` and `<string.h>` and other headers.  The system must make it work.

If each of the headers you include is itself idempotent (meaning it doesn't cause trouble if it is included more than once in a TU), there won't be problems.

And in yet another [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77701939/c-c-duplicate-header-file-inclusions-across-multiple-files-preprocessor-c/77705375?noredirect=1#comment136992465_77705375), they ask:

> […] It would cause an error if I had included `apputil.h` guards in a different form in all 3 `.h` files, right?

This is a bit difficult to parse, too.  If you're still thinking of applying the header guards in code that includes the header rather than the header itself, then (a) you're doing it the wrong way (don't do it!), and (b) if you used different names in the header guard sequences in different places, you would probably, but not necessarily, end up with problems.

If the headers are not self-protecting and rely on the including code to protect them from multiple inclusion, you have to ensure that all the places that include a given header protect it the same way.  In general, not being 100% consistent will cause problems because the same type (structure, union or enumeration) will be defined twice, which is not allowed.  However, if the header only declares functions, you may well get away with it.  But the fact that you have four lines of code per file including each header instead of just the one `#include` line means you are making busy-work for yourself.  (I trust you don't have a team you're working with and penalizing with your bad code design decisions.)

Please, please, please abandon any thoughts of protecting headers outside the header file.  The header guard inside the header file is the idiomatic and sensible way to protect headers.  Anything else is error prone and creates extra work for the teams using those headers.

---

<sup>(1) Strictly, if the headers contain the header guards, it doesn't matter if the header guards change as long as they remain unique across all header files used by the translation unit (TU).  The test for the wrong header guard simply means the header is included, but since it contains its own header guards, no great damage is done, though the intent behind testing the header guards in the source file including the header was to prevent reinclusion.  The compilers do a good job of avoiding reinclusion when the header has the standard layout.  If you don't try to optimize by testing the header guards in the code including the header, you don't run into these problems.</sup>

Comment: thank you. i would need to set aside some time to thoroughly go over the links you provided, but one final expansion upon this - it is exactly because the header guard would prevent a double inclusion that i ask this. if i had included other headers i needed for each module within the guard __such that the contents within the guard are different in each module, that would definitely cause issue, right__?

Comment: obviously this is just to understand the technicality - it would cause error if i had included apputil.h guards in different form in all 3 h files right?

Comment: i could test it, but have no sure way to determine if this would be the exact cause of any compiler error.

Comment: I'm not sure if you get notified about edits to an answer to one of your questions.  Just in case, I've addressed your first two comments above in an extra edit.